# Can you use Spring-Cloud-Stream 3 without binders (Kafka/RabbitMQ)?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-stream

Is it possible to not need a binder for Spring-Cloud-Stream 3? If I have simple code like:

```
@Bean
public Supplier<LoggingConsumerApplication.Person> generate() {
    return () -> {
        Person person = new Person();
        person.setName("John");
        return person;
    };
}

@Bean
public Function<Person, Void> capitalize() {
    return person -> {
        person.setName(person.getName().toUpperCase());
        System.out.println(person.getName());
        return null;
    };
}
```

With my application.properties like:

```
spring.cloud.function.definition=generate|capitalize;
```

Why do I need to use Kafka or RabbitMQ at all? Is there a way to transfer between generate and capitalize just through the app (like with Spring Cloud Stream 1.x)?

Comment: I am not even sure what you're asking especially when you say `like with Spring Cloud Stream 1.x` which had non of the above. What you're showing is two beans of type function and supplier and that is all. So please help me understand . . .

Comment: @Oleg Zhurakousky I mean is there a way for me to run this exact code without turning on a kafka server (or rabbitmq server or any other external server to bind the functions) Can this code run by itself? Currently, Im using the kafka-binder with a local kafka server, but it is not feasible in my use case to deploy this.

Comment: @OlegZhurakousky Can I bind the functions internally within the application instead of through an external broker server (like Kafka, RabbitMQ, etc)

Comment: You can simply use [spring-cloud-function](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-function) project the same way spring-cloud-stream is using it. Access `FunctionCatalog` bean and `lookup("generate|capitalize")`.

Comment: This question is utterly confusing. Why *on Earth* would you want to use Spring Cloud Stream without a binder? The whole purpose of Spring Cloud Stream is to provide an abstraction over a messaging system. If you don't want that, why are you even trying to use Spring Cloud Stream at all? If the two beans are part of the same app, one can simply call the other one directly, how on Earth does SCS suddenly come into the picture?